# Binary classifier only predicting one class after undersampling my data

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, convolutional-neural-network

I'm trying to classify doublets of images into 2 categories. My initial results where poor and I thought that this was because my classes were heavily imbalance (about 88-12). I've under sampled my data and used a two branch network with convolutions. My model gets around 50% accuracy on the training set at each epoch and then 85 on the testing data. I'm really confused about what to do to solve this problem.

```
XZ_input = keras.Input( shape = (100,80,1), name = 'xz_img')
YZ_input = keras.Input( shape = (100,80,1), name = 'yz_img')

xz = layers.Conv2D(8, (3,3), activation = 'relu', padding= 'same')(XZ_input)
xz = layers.MaxPooling2D((3,3))(xz)
xz = layers.Flatten()(xz)

yz = layers.Conv2D(8, (3,3), activation = 'relu', padding= 'same')(YZ_input)
yz = layers.MaxPooling2D((3,3))(yz)
yz = layers.Flatten()(yz)

x = layers.concatenate([xz,yz])
x = layers.Dense(20, activation = 'relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = layers.Dense(5, activation = 'relu')(x)

pred = layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(x)

model = keras.Model(
    inputs=[XZ_input, YZ_input],
    outputs=[pred])
model.summary()
```

```
majority_indices = np.where(y_train ==1)[0]
minority_indices = np.where(y_train == 0)[0]
random_majority_indices = np.random.choice(majority_indices,len(minority_indices), replace = False )
under_sampling = np.concatenate([random_majority_indices, minority_indices])
y_train = y_train[under_sampling]
X_train = X_train[under_sampling]
X__train = X_train.reshape(y_train.shape[0],2,100,80)
X1__train = X__train[:,0].reshape(y_train.shape[0], 100,80,1)
X2__train = X__train[:,1].reshape(y_train.shape[0], 100,80,1)

model.fit({'xz_img': X1__train, 'yz_img': X2__train},y_train, epochs = 10, batch_size = 500, validation_data = ([X1__test, X2__test], y_test))
```

output:

```
Epoch 1/10
24/24 [==============================] - 42s 2s/step - loss: 0.6922 - binary_accuracy: 0.5048 - val_loss: 0.6884 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8290
Epoch 2/10
24/24 [==============================] - 37s 2s/step - loss: 0.6911 - binary_accuracy: 0.5195 - val_loss: 0.6849 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8442
Epoch 3/10
24/24 [==============================] - 35s 1s/step - loss: 0.6891 - binary_accuracy: 0.5193 - val_loss: 0.6783 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8528
Epoch 4/10
24/24 [==============================] - 35s 1s/step - loss: 0.6861 - binary_accuracy: 0.5207 - val_loss: 0.6688 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8609
Epoch 5/10
24/24 [==============================] - 34s 1s/step - loss: 0.6827 - binary_accuracy: 0.5099 - val_loss: 0.6582 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8680
Epoch 6/10
24/24 [==============================] - 34s 1s/step - loss: 0.6794 - binary_accuracy: 0.5115 - val_loss: 0.6511 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8552
Epoch 7/10
24/24 [==============================] - 34s 1s/step - loss: 0.6765 - binary_accuracy: 0.5163 - val_loss: 0.6447 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8379
Epoch 8/10
24/24 [==============================] - 39s 2s/step - loss: 0.6738 - binary_accuracy: 0.5309 - val_loss: 0.6399 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8043
Epoch 9/10
24/24 [==============================] - 35s 1s/step - loss: 0.6715 - binary_accuracy: 0.5503 - val_loss: 0.6347 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.7772
Epoch 10/10
24/24 [==============================] - 35s 1s/step - loss: 0.6691 - binary_accuracy: 0.5609 - val_loss: 0.6292 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.7567
Out[44]:
```

A bit of analysis:

```
pred = model.predict([X1__test, X2__test])

pred[:10], y_test[:10]

(array([[0.50534785],
        [0.5246037 ],
        [0.503593  ],
        [0.49585894],
        [0.49691   ],
        [0.49851283],
        [0.509586  ],
        [0.5941074 ],
        [0.63272274],
        [0.5186754 ]], dtype=float32),
 array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]))
```

Basically, my model is no better than flipping a coin..

Comment: With more information on the type of problem and data you are working on it may be a bit difficult to fully understand why your model is not performing well. Have you tried increasing the number of convolutional filters, convolutional layers, and the number of neurons in your fully connected layers?

Comment: I'm classifying images taken on the xz plane and the yz plane of neutrino interactions. From the images, I'm trying to predict what interaction took place between the particles. I've tried a bunch of things but my model essentially only predicts one class. Let me know if this helps

Comment: This helps a bit, but can you be a bit more specific on different things you have tried? In addition, are you able to share (a subsample of) the data you are training the model? I would first try to overfit the model on a single batch on data (i.e. get the loss very low) to make that the model is at least able to learn patterns from the data.